# User Profile: Birthday VS Anniversary

Tags: database, user-profile, date, fullcontact

I am creating a contact list and as usual I like to see how others do it. I went to see full-contact and they have 2 fields on the users profile, one for birthday and another for anniversary.

I thought that they where the same, but apparently they are not.

Does anyone knows the difference between he two?

If you know why, then why is that full-contact is using both?

Which one should I use?

Comment: "Birthday" is the day you were born, "anniversary" in English speaking countries is typically used for the day you were married.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the "Birthday Represent the date of birth while the "Anniversary" represents the day of marriage.